# Owl Carousel 2 find center item

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I want to find `center` item, in owl carousel 2 (in native) not select by `class` like `$('.owl-item.center')` I want to find it by owl carousel native function and result, now I can get event, and there are bunch of results, I can get any value related to `center`

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  center: true,
  items: 3,
  loop: false,
  margin: 10,
});

$('.owl-carousel').on("dragged.owl.carousel", function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  if (e.itemClass === 'center') {
    alert('it is center one!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha256-UhQQ4fxEeABh4JrcmAJ1+16id/1dnlOEVCFOxDef9Lw=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha256-pTxD+DSzIwmwhOqTFN+DB+nHjO4iAsbgfyFq5K5bcE0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <h4>1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>3</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>4</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>5</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>6</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

how can I detect owl carousel 2 center item in native? again, I don't want to find jquery find items by `center` class with `find` `each` or any other selector, I want to owl give it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think owl carousel provide such option to get center item in event result. you can do this littly tricky like this, just get `e.item.index` it is current active item, then `+1` to get centered item. check example below:

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  center: true,
  items: 3,
  loop: false,
  margin: 10,
});

$('.owl-carousel').on("dragged.owl.carousel", function(e) {
  console.log('center item is:'+ (e.item.index + 1));
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.owl-item.active.center {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha256-UhQQ4fxEeABh4JrcmAJ1+16id/1dnlOEVCFOxDef9Lw=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha256-pTxD+DSzIwmwhOqTFN+DB+nHjO4iAsbgfyFq5K5bcE0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <h4>1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>3</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>4</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>5</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>6</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```